# Bari BRI to Rome Fiumicino FCO Ryanair On Time Peformance - Is this doable?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, rome, ryanair

My flight plan (Return Ticket by Ryanair) will be

- 29 March - FCO to BRI (I will leave my luggage at [FCO Luggage
  Storage](http://www.adr.it/web/aeroporti-di-roma-en-/pax-fco-baggage-services) open from 6:30am to 11:30pm)
- 30 March BRI to FCO 18:40 to 19:45

As Luggage Counter closes at 11:30pm & my flight lands at 7:45pm, I will have total 3:45 hours to clear/pass the disembarking from plane walk/find & fetch luggage. From then on, I have a FCO-AMS KLM flight next day @ 3:30am 31 March.

Will I have enough time to get off from BRI-FCO Ryanair flight @ FCO Airport & fetch luggage from its Luggage Storage section? Does Ryanair have history of on-time arrivals?

Other details, if matter:

- Visa- Schengen Type C Multi, Nationality Indian
- I will leave Luggage at FCO because trip to BRI is a quick one, & Ryanair will charge this as this is 10+ Kg).
- Current KLM Route : DEL-AMS-FCO, FCO-AMS-DEL

Edit:
Also, I am carrying my camera bag as carry-on, it is less than 10KG, but I have heard that if the Cabin fills up quickly, they ask the remaining passengers to check-in their carry-on luggage without any cost, at gate. As I will be carrying camera & lenses, can I refuse to accept their offer? On KLM flights, it usually fits under the seat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it looks quite leisurely (excluding the godawful 0330 flight the next day—when do you intend to sleep??). I would imagine that if you did this 100 times, only five or six times would something go seriously wrong.

With that in mind, what is your plan if the Ryanair flight is cancelled altogether. Are you okay with rebooking your KLM flight? What would you do if you couldn't get your luggage?

I think your plan will work, but you do always need a plan B. If your plan B is annoying but acceptable ("I'll stop by the airport shop to buy new pants"), then go with it. If your plan B is "Oh no I don't have my insulin" then perhaps reconsider.

Comment: :(.. Can't postpone KLM flight, as I need to be out of Schengen on 31 March 23:59:59 (The current booked flight is FCO-AMS-Out). If Ryanair cancels or gets late, & I could not get my luggage, don't know how will I get it back, although it will have usual travel-clothes etc. But essiantlly I will be abandoning it. & Not getting on FCO-AMS will also get the next leg from AMS cancelled for me.

Comment: The other option I am looking is Train, or the safer option, travel BRI in between of my 9 days ROME trip, leaving luggage in Hotel, or safest, do not travel to BRI, as it is just to see a long-seen family member.

Comment: KLM flies from BRI do they not? Can you get your existing itinerary repriced to return from Bristol instead of Rome?

Comment: that is also a good idea, let me look into the prices. By this, I just need to pay either one-way trail (EUR 19), then KLM for price change. Thanks.. Will report the findings.

Comment: Checked, my original KLM Route is DEL-AMS-FCO & FCO-AMS-DEL, but if I start my return leg from BRI with KLM, they offer me BRI-AMS-AUH-DEL & EUR 320 extra, & all this return leg is on partner airlines, not KLM itself, although all on one single KLM ticket. Although by this, I will save EUR 94 from Hotel Booking (less two nights)

Answer (score 3):

Ryanair's punctuality is good - [they claim the best of any European airline](http://corporate.ryanair.com/about-us/punctuality/), with ~90%, although [there is some dispute about the breadth of data used for the claim](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-22659822). My personal experience is that their is a degree of "padding" in Ryanair schedules, to allow for that broadly on tme claim.  I've been on a Ryanair flight that proudly announced arriving considerably early - however as I left the gate, I noticed that the next flight from the gate (also Ryanair) was scheduled to depart at what had been our scheduled landing time.

That said, flights can always be delayed or cancelled for a variety of reasons. If you need to be at AMS for the 31 March, you'd be advised to plan to ensure it is possible. Trains are always a viable option as you say.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, looking for trains now, also have decided to move the dates 1 or 2 days earlier, keep the luggage in hotel room.

Comment: The "padding" is real -- compare other flights at similar times on the same route.

Comment: What is your opinion about Ryan-air checked-in luggage chances of delivery? I belivee it will be same as any other airline, ~99.9% Because if they loose/delay it, I will again be in hot waters. Charges Luggage 15KG FCO-BRI-FCO are EUR 55, but then I could save two nights EUR 94 from hotel.

Comment: Ryanair claim to lose less luggage tehn any other European airline as well - but that doesn't mean that it can't happen. Equally, trains can be delayed cancelled, etc etc. THings can go wrong when travelling. You can't engineer out all risk. What you can do is plan in allowances and contingencies. You can plan so that if one flight goes wrong, you still have ways to get to where you need to be, if perhaps a bit later and a few € lighter.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your question about the camera bag: if it fits under the seat, then you can always argue with the gate agents that you will put it there. Usually they only mark large suitcases to be checked in instead of carry-on. Boarding early also reduces the probability of such a procedure.

Instead please not that if your flight from BRI to FCO is delayed considerably you will not only be unable to pick up your luggage but might even miss your FCO to AMS flight. That is a risk I would try to avoid. Could you travel a day earlier instead?

And as for you true question: if the flight is on time you have plenty of time to pick up your luggage but in case it is not you are in some trouble. How much would be the cost to check in your luggage to BRI and back compared to luggage storage at FCO in the end?

Comment: Thanks, yes I am considering to travel to BRI on 4th or 5th day of my 9 day Rome trip, instead of on 8th day. Ryanair shows EUR 10 for 10KG & 20 for 10-19KG per leg (40 for total FCO-BRI Return Trip 13KG)The Luggage Counter fees is EUR 6 for 24 Hours per suitcase (12 EUR total as per my intended usage)

Comment: Ryanair is charging EUR 55 (Return) for Luggage 15KG FCO-BRI. Comparing all options..